# Github CI/CD fails when I try to deploy React Native iOS to appcenter

Tags: xcode, react-native, github-actions, fastlane, metro-bundler

React Native CI fails on build iOS step:

```
- name: Build iOS (Debug)
    uses: yukiarrr/ios-build-action@v1.5.0
    with:
      configuration: Debug
      project-path: ios/AppName.xcodeproj
      p12-base64: ${{ secrets.P12_BASE64 }}
      mobileprovision-base64: ${{ secrets.MOBILEPROVISION_BASE64 }}
      code-signing-identity: "Apple Distribution"
      certificate-password: ${{ secrets.CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD }}
      team-id: ${{ secrets.IOS_TEAM_ID }}
      workspace-path: ios/AppName.xcworkspace
      output-path: "AppName.ipa"
```

The step above outputs the following:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-eyrioodbvepenugnskmjmdofbdnt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/AppName.build/Release-iphoneos/AppName.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'AppName' from project 'AppName')
(1 failure)
[10:35:43]: Exit status: 65
[10:35:43]: 
[10:35:43]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[10:35:43]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[10:35:43]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[10:35:43]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode_14.2.app'
[10:35:43]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[10:35:43]: 
[10:35:43]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[10:35:43]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[10:35:43]: 
[10:35:43]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[10:35:43]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[10:35:43]: 
[10:35:43]: - Manually update the path using
[10:35:43]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[10:35:43]: 

+---------------+------------------------------+
|              Build environment               |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app |
| gym_version   | 2.214.0                      |
| export_method | app-store                    |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk             |
+---------------+------------------------------+

[10:35:43]: ▸     at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/runner/work/AppName-mobile/AppName-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
[10:35:43]: ▸     at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/runner/work/AppName-mobile/AppName-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
[10:35:43]: ▸     at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/Users/runner/work/AppName-mobile/AppName-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)
[10:35:43]: ▸ info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
[10:35:43]: ▸ Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
[10:35:43]: 
[10:35:43]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[10:35:43]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[10:35:43]:   /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/AppName-AppName.log
[10:35:43]: 
[10:35:43]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[10:35:43]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[10:35:43]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[10:35:43]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[10:35:43]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[10:35:43]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[10:35:43]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[10:35:43]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[10:35:43]: 
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                  Lane Context                                   |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM          | ios                                                 |
| PLATFORM_NAME             | ios                                                 |
| LANE_NAME                 | ios export_ipa                                      |
| KEYCHAIN_PATH             | ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain              |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN | "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
[10:35:43]: Error building the application - see the log above

+------+------------------------------+-------------+
|                 fastlane summary                  |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                       | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform             | 0           |
| 2    | create_keychain              | 0           |
| 3    | import_certificate           | 0           |
| 4    | install_provisioning_profile | 0           |
| 5    | update_code_signing_settings | 0           |
| 6    | update_project_provisioning  | 0           |
| 7    | update_project_team          | 0           |
|    | build_app                    | 687         |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+

[10:35:43]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error building the application - see the log above
Error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

When I check .log file, I see the following exception at the end:

```
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6191770Z                     Welcome to Metro!
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6192750Z               Fast - Scalable - Integrated
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6193160Z 
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6193180Z 
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6194640Z Failed to construct transformer:  Error:     error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6195380Z     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6195720Z     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6196500Z     at stableHash (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6197780Z     at Object.getCacheKey (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:593:7)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6198430Z     at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6198970Z     at new Transformer (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:48:9)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6199400Z     at /Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:22:29
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6199680Z     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6200550Z   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6200900Z   library: 'digital envelope routines',
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6201100Z   reason: 'unsupported',
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6201350Z   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6201450Z }
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6202030Z error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile').
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6203020Z TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6204310Z     at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6204610Z     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6205170Z     at async Object.transform (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6205800Z     at async processModule (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6206820Z     at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6207050Z     at async Promise.all (index 0)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6207700Z     at async initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6208740Z     at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6209330Z     at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6209860Z     at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/Users/runner/work/myproject-mobile/myproject-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6211670Z info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
2023-08-07T19:16:49.6213560Z Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Any ideas? it already transformed my life to hell

Comment: Hello. Could you share information about NodeJS version on your local machine and CI?